# Using node-spotify-web-api to grant user access and fetch data

Tags: api, express, spotify

So I'm new to using OAuth and I honestly got quite lost trying to make this work. I looked up the documentation for [Spotify's Authorization code](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow) and also found a [wrapper for node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spotify-web-api-node) which I used.

I want to be able to log in a user through spotify and from there do API calls to the Spotify API.

Looking through an example, I ended up with this code for the `/callback` route which is hit after the user is granted access and  Spotify Accounts services redirects you there:

```
app.get('/callback', (req, res) => {
  const { code, state } = req.query;
  const storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[STATE_KEY] : null;

  if (state === null || state !== storedState) {
    res.redirect('/#/error/state mismatch');

  } else {
    res.clearCookie(STATE_KEY);

    spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(code).then(data => {
      const { expires_in, access_token, refresh_token } = data.body;

      // Set the access token on the API object to use it in later calls
      spotifyApi.setAccessToken(access_token);
      spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(refresh_token);

      // use the access token to access the Spotify Web API
      spotifyApi.getMe().then(({ body }) => {
        console.log(body);
      });


      res.redirect(`/#/user/${access_token}/${refresh_token}`);
    }).catch(err => {
      res.redirect('/#/error/invalid token');
    });
  }
});
```

So above, at the end of the request the token is passed to the browser to make requests from there: `res.redirect('/#/user/${access_token}/${refresh_token}');`

What if insted of redirecting there, I want to redirect a user to a form where he can search for artists. Do I need so somehow pass the token around the params at all time? How would I redirect a user there? I tried simply rendering a new page and passing params there but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

you could store the tokens in a variety of places, including the query parameters or cookies - but I'd recommend using [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). When your frontend loads the `/#/user/${access_token}/${refresh_token}` route, you could grab the values and store them in localstorage (e.g. `localstorage.set('accessToken', accessToken)`) and retrieve them later when you need to make calls to the API.